# Users can only view their Data

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want to create a statement to make sure users can only view their own call_center data unless their role_id is 2, 3, or 4. As of right now if the URL is venture.local/?call_center=77 and the user changes the URL to venture.local/?call_center=22 anyone role_id can see other call_center data. I want the page to return to the users own call_center unless their role_id is 2, 3, or 4. I am not sure if the best pace to make this work is in JavaScript or my dashboardcontroller.php? I've included my controller because I think I can do something like this:

```
 if($role_id['id'] != '2' || $role_id['id'] != '3' || $role_id['id'] != '4')
        {
        $pending->where($call_center, '=', $user_id);
        $active->where($call_center, '=', $user_id);
        $cancelled_contracts->where($call_center, '=', $user_id);
        $late_contracts->where($call_center, '=', $user_id);
        $back_out_contracts->where($call_center, '=', $user_id);
        $pending_late->where($call_center, '=', $user_id);
        $pending_cancellation->where($call_center, '=', $user_id);
        }
```

Am i in the right direction?Or can someone direct me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated.

> Dashboardcontroller.php

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.utf8');
        $this->middleware('acl:view_dash', ['only' => ['index']]);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $input = Input::all();

        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $role_id = User::UserRoleData()->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->first();
        $call_center = Auth::user()->call_center;
        $call_center = ($call_center == null ? '' : $call_center);
        $call_center = !empty($input['call_center']) ? $input['call_center'] : $call_center;
        $month = !empty($input['month']) ? $input['month'] : 'twentyfour';
        $sellertype = !empty($input['sellertype']) ? $input['sellertype'] : 'seller';
        $companies = Company::DistinctCompanies()->orderby('name')->get();
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now -24 months'));

        if($user_id()->call_center)
        {
        $user 
        }

        $pending = Contract::GetData()
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->where('system_status', '=', 'Pending')
            ->where('hold', '=', '0');

        $active = Contract::GetData()
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->where('system_status', '=', 'Active')
            ->where('hold', '=', '0');

        $cancelled_contracts = Contract::GetData()
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->where('system_status', '=', 'Cancelled')
            ->where('hold', '=', '0');

        $late_contracts = Contract::GetData()
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->where('system_status', '=', 'Late')
            ->where('hold', '=', '0');

        $back_out_contracts = Contract::GetData()
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->where('system_status', '=', 'Back Out')
            ->where('hold', '=', '0');

        $pending_late = Contract::GetData()
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->where('system_status', '=', 'Pending Late')
            ->where('hold', '=', '0');

        $pending_cancellation = Contract::GetData()
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->where('system_status', '=', 'Awaiting Cancellation')
            ->where('hold', '=', '0');

        if($sellertype == 'dealership')
        {
        $pending->where("type", "=", 'dealership');
        $active->where("type", "=", 'dealership');
        $cancelled_contracts->where("type", "=", 'dealership');
        $late_contracts->where("type", "=", 'dealership');
        $back_out_contracts->where("type", "=", 'dealership');
        $pending_late->where("type", "=", 'dealership');
        $pending_cancellation->where("type", "=", 'dealership');
        }

        if($month == 'twentyfour' || $month != 'all')
        {
            $pending->where("sold_date", ">=", $date);
            $active->where("sold_date", ">=", $date);
            $cancelled_contracts->where("sold_date", ">=", $date);
            $late_contracts->where("sold_date", ">=", $date);
            $back_out_contracts->where("sold_date", ">=", $date);
            $pending_late->where("sold_date", ">=", $date);
            $pending_cancellation->where("sold_date", ">=", $date);
        }
        if($call_center == '52')
        {
            $asi_contracts = array('26', '35', '4', '42', '45', '46', '47', '49', '50', '51');
            $pending
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%');

            $active
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%');

            $cancelled_contracts
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%');

            $late_contracts
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%');

            $back_out_contracts
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%');

            $pending_late
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%');

            $pending_cancellation
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')
                ->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%');

        }

        if($role_id['id'] == '5' || $role_id['id'] == '6' || $role_id['id'] == '7' || $role_id['id'] == '8' || $role_id['id'] == '9' || $role_id['id'] == '10')
        {
            {
                $pending->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                $active->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                $cancelled_contracts->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                $late_contracts->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                $back_out_contracts->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                $pending_late->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                $pending_cancellation->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if($role_id['id'] == '2' && !empty($input['call_center']))
            {
                $call_center = $input['call_center'];
                {
                    $pending->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                    $active->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                    $cancelled_contracts->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                    $late_contracts->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                    $back_out_contracts->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                    $pending_late->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                    $pending_cancellation->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You might want to go through https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization before rolling your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your User model, if you don't already have roles set up as a relationship, you can do the following:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}

public function hasRole($roleName) : bool
{
    // you could always change this function so it could take
    // an array of role IDs instead of the name

    $roles = $this->roles()->where('name', roleName)->firstOrFail();

    if ($roles) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

In your call centre model, you can set up a function like so:

```
public function canBeViewedBy(User $user) : bool
{
    // customise role name to whichever roles you want

    if ($user->hasRole('canViewAllCentres') {
        return true;
    }

    // you can add additional custom logic here

    return false;
}
```

Then inside your function in your Dashboard controller:

```
if (!$call_center->canBeViewedBy(Auth::user()) {
    return abort(403, 'Forbidden');
}
```

Comment: Also, bonus handy tip! `$user_id = Auth::user()->id;` is the same as `Auth::id();` :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all stop passing the data like that in the URL. Use session upon user login to handle this, if possible.

If you don't like the above approach, then you can use Encryption / Decryption for this purpose. Never pass raw number like 22 or 33 in the URL. Don't make the end user curious.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

$encrypted = Crypt::encryptString('123');

$decrypted = Crypt::decryptString($encrypted);
```

Also, you can read Laravel Authorization documentation, it is useful for the exact problem you're facing.